# Python login script

Tags: python, scripting

I have the following script to logon to a url,but on submit in the webpage i call

```
<input type=button value="go"  onclick="Search()";>
```

How to do the same in the following script instead of submit......

```
import urllib, urllib2, time
username = "sumname"
password = "test"
interval = 10
data = {"username":username,"password":password,"submit":"sign in"}
value = urllib.urlencode(data)
request = urllib2.Request("http://127.0.0.1/accounts/login/",value)
print "request="%request
#while (1):
open = urllib2.urlopen(request)
response = open.read()
response=str(response)
print response
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urllib and urllib2 are not the best ways to simulate browser interaction!  You should rather be looking at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) (which does plug into urllib2).  It's possible to simulate such interaction on "bare" urllib2, but it's just too much work and fragility to bother;-).

Comment: Thanks Alex........urlib2 served my purpose in this case.....I got a script that is finally working....